# Find Number of 0's at end of int

Tags: c#, console-application

I wanted to find out the number of 0's at end of integer.
Suppose anyone enter **2020 it should count 1**,if number is **2000 it should show 3** etc;

I tried following but doesn't accomplish what i want :(

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Number :");
int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int count = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < num.ToString().Count(); i++)
{
   //some logic
}

Console.WriteLine("Zero in the tail is :");
Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Comment: You have unlocked a relic as @Jon-Skeet answered your question and nobody dared to say it's a homework question!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're not changing anything within your loop - so basically, on each iteration it will either increase `Count` or it won't, and it'll do the same thing each time - so `Count` will either be the length of the string, or it will be 0.

The simplest option I can think of in terms of text manipulation would be:

```
string text = num.ToString();
int count = text.Length - text.TrimEnd('0').Length;
```

Without using text manipulation, however, you could just use division and remainder operations:

```
int count = 0;
// Keep going while the last digit is 0
while (num > 0 && num % 10 == 0)
{
    num = num / 10;
    count++;
}
```

Note that this will yield a count of 0 for the number 0... whereas the first approach will give a count of 1 (because `0.ToString()` is "0"). Adjust either piece of code to suit your requirements :)

Comment: That is what I was thinking of, But string's available operations are making new ones far from maths/algorithm.

Comment: @Ammar: Not sure what you mean here - I gave one string approach, and one non-string approach...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your answer as I appreciated it, I want to say that the second one is best.

Comment: @Ammar: What do you mean by "the second one"? (Answers are shown in an order that you control - whose answer do you mean?)

Comment: I think Ammar was referring to your second approach (the non-string one) when he wrote "the second one".

Answer (score 2):

```
    int GetTrailingZerosFromInteger(int no)
    {
        if (no == 0)
            return 1;

        int count = 0;
        while(no % 10 == 0)
        {
            no /= 10;
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also go the maths way

```
           int n  = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
           int totalzero = 0 ;
           while(n > 0){
             int digit = n % 10;
             if(digit == 0)
                 totalzero++;
             else
                break;
             n = n / 10;
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by just iterating the string from the back something like this:

```
var strN = 40300.ToString();
int count = 0;
for (var i = strN.Length - 1; strN[i] == '0'; --i, ++count) ;

Console.WriteLine("Result : " + count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since a 32-bit integer can have at most nine zeros you can unroll the loop in quite a pleasing way:

```
int digits =
    num == 0 ? 0 :
    num % 1000000000 == 0 ? 9 :
    num % 100000000 == 0 ? 8 :
    num % 10000000 == 0 ? 7 :
    num % 1000000 == 0 ? 6 :
    num % 100000 == 0 ? 5 :
    num % 10000 == 0 ? 4 :
    num % 1000 == 0 ? 3 :
    num % 100 == 0 ? 2 :
    num % 10 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
```